# Give commit access to everyone on GitHub

Tags: github, permissions, repository, github-pages, wiki

Is there a way to give commit access to everyone on a public repository on GitHub? I want to use that repo as an alternative to GitHub Wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to invest some more work and resources into this, you can probably automate this with [pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/) and the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/).

I don't have the source code, but I know an example where someone did exactly this:
https://github.com/robashton/crowdsourcedhomepage

Quote from the readme:

> Stick anything ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°) you like in here (make pull requests to the
>   branch "gh-pages").
>
> Every pull request will be automatically merged if possible, and then
>   it'll end up on the home page of http://codeofrob.com

---

I didn't try it myself, but implementing something like this should be relatively simple:
At first glance, you just need a server/cronjob/whatever which uses the GitHub API [to check your repo for new pull requests](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#list-pull-requests) and [to auto-merge each one](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#merge-a-pull-request-merge-button).

Answer (score 2):

No, it would be read only for any anonymous user, of for any user you did not explicitly grant permission, either directly or [through an organization](https://help.github.com/articles/differences-between-user-and-organization-accounts/).

But anyone will be able to **[fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/)** your repo and proposes [pull requests](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/).